# Higher order homology operations for diagrams of chain complexes (reference request)

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a small category enriched in $\mathcal{A}b$, the category of abelian groups (my adviser enjoys calling these "many-object rings"). Given a diagram $M:R\to\mathcal{A}b$, taking homology gives us an $R$-diagram of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded abelian groups $H_\bullet M$. I would like to describe algebraic data that allows us to reconstruct $M$ (up to a zig-zag of quasi-isomorphisms -- i.e. the homotopy type of $M$) from $H_\bullet M$. In other words, I am looking for algebraic data that captures the homotopy coherence data of this diagram.

A first step in this direction is to note that $M$ determines homology operations beyond just the morphisms of $R$. Let $R$ be (the free $\mathcal{A}b$-enrichment of) a commutative square: $$\begin{matrix}A&\stackrel{f_1}{\to}&B\\\downarrow f_2&&\downarrow g_1\\C&\stackrel{g_2}{\to}&D\end{matrix}$$

Then we get a map $\mathrm{ker}\,H_i\, f_1\cap \mathrm{ker}\,H_i\, f_2\to H_{i+1}\,D/\left(\mathrm{im}\,H_{i+1}\,g_1\oplus \mathrm{im}\,H_{i+1}\,g_2\right)$. This comes about as follows: For a homology class in $H_i \,\mathrm{ker}\, f_1\cap H_i \,\mathrm{ker}\, f_2$ pick a representing cycle $a$. By assumption, we can lift $f_1 a$ and $f_2 a$ along the differential. Pick such lifts and call them $a_1$ and $a_2$. By the commutativity of the square, $g_1 (a_1)-g_2 (a_2)$ is a cycle in $D$. There was some ambiguity in our choice of lifts of $a$, but passing to the indicated quotient makes things well-defined.

Note that when $B=0=C$, this operation gives us a map $H_\bullet A[1]\to D$ -- in other words, a map from the homology of the suspension of $A$ (the homotopy colimit of the span) to the homology of $D$, just as we would expect.

Similar, higher-order operations can be defined when $R$ is a higher-dimensional cube. In general, if we're given an $R$-indexed diagram of graded abelian groups coming from a diagram of chain complexes $M$, specifying the operations induced by cubes in $R$ is a step toward recovering (the (homotopy type of) $M$.

Finally I come to my question: is there a reference where the basic properties of these and similar operations are worked out? The construction I describe seems so elementary that it must appear in the literature somewhere, but I haven't been able to find anything so far. Even a discussion of these operations when $R$ has a single object (i.e. is a ring) would be of interest: note that a commutative square in a ring $R$ is quadruple of elements $r,s,t,u$ such that $rs=tu$, and in this case, the construction is related to the Massey product.

Comment: A way to develop spectral sequences is through Massey's exact couples, but I have not seen such things for a square.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea you're right though -- I should probably be thinking along the lines of the Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence.